# new app-tailwind-input gives me undefined behavior

Tags: angular, frontend

Hey I just started working with angular so I hope this is not a dumb question. I changed the old `mat-form-field` to `app-tailwind-input` but in my input field I get now `undefined` and the default text is outside of my field.

here is what it looks like after the change
[image]

Here's what my code looks like:

```html
<app-tailwind-input
    *ngIf="data.level > 0"
    appearance="outline"
    class="removeBottomPaddingMatFormField">
        <input
          matInput
          currencyMask
          required
          autocomplete="off"
          #amountInput="ngModel"
          name="amount"
          [disabled]="data.group.margin !== 0" 
          (ngModelChange)="amountValueChange($event, amountInput, data, column)"
          [options]="getInputCurrencyOptions(column)" 
          [ngModel]="data.amount[i].amount">
</app-tailwind-input>
```

has somebody an idea how I get my default text back in the field and not have undefined?

Comment: I suppose `app-tailwind-input` is a component you generated. Without revealing that code, I dont think anybody could help you out.

Comment: Where is your default text supposed to come from? Are you providing that value in the code you are showing us?  If not... there's no way anyone can know how to answer your question